# Android database operations and return values

Tags: android, mysql

Say I have a method to insert a product that returns a boolean value dependent on whether the insert was successful or not:

```
public boolean insertProduct(Product product) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", product.name);
    values.put("price", product.price);
    boolean inserted = true;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.insertOrThrow("products",null,values);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        inserted = false;
    }
    return inserted;
}
```

If in another activity I have:

```
boolean productAdded = dbHelper.insertProduct(newProduct);
if (productAdded) {
     // do something
} else {
     // do something else
}
```

I know that database inserts take some time (possibly a relatively long time on really slow devices), so is this a safe way to test whether the insert was successful? Will `if (productAdded)` wait until it gets the return value from the `insertProduct()` method and will the method wait to return the `inserted` boolean until the insert was successful or failed?

Comment: yes it would have a slight delay.. a delay that is not quite noticeable to users... One option is to call it inside an asynchronous task..you could also utilize db.insert(); which returns -1 if insert failed..and returns a long number if insertion is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will if (productAdded) wait until it gets the return value from the `insertProduct()` method??

```
Yes it will Wait.
```

By default all Sqlite DB opeartions perfom on the UI thread only.

Comment: Cool. But will the method also wait to return the value? if `db.insertOrThrow()` takes half a second (for example), with the return statement wait until try/catch is resolved/completed?

Comment: @TimSim whatever time it will taken,it wait for for the result and if statement executes then only..Read Single threading and multi threading concept

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default, each execution statement is synchronous. That means every statement will wait for the Right Hand side operation to complete before the assignment to the Left Hand Side. It is not just with database calls. Every statement that takes a while will effectively hold up the code execution till it completes, and hence the need for async methodologies.

In your case, yes, it is safe to assume that the boolean returned will be the correct value of the complete function execution, but as you rightly pointed out, it will take time, and can hold up code. In android, you can consider moving this code to async tasks and triggering the other activity to run it's function via a handler from the onPostExecute of the async task.

Answer (score 1):

The insertOrThrow method of SqliteDatabase also returns a long value, that represents the id of the row inserted. You can also check that long value that if long value is -1 then no row is inserted but if it has value other than -1 then row is successfully inserted.